# In a razor why, why can't I use "??" (more inside)

Tags: razor

First of all, please forgive me if this question is too basic or otherwise laughable.  The question is, why doesn't this work in a Razor view:

```
@item.Clients.Where(u => u.IsActive).FirstOrDefault().Name.Any() ?? "(None Exist)"
```

If this Client Name field exists, then I want it to be displayed in this View, and if it doesn't exist, I need the "(None Exist)" string to be displayed.

Comment: What is the result of the `Any()` call?

Comment: IIRC, the Razor engine can't compile C#6 code yet. I was looking for something similar a couple months ago.

Comment: Any() return true just fine, but when there is a null .Any() fails and results in a null reference exception.